# 6 different people in queue

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Six people, including $A,B,$ and $C$, form a queue in a random order (all $6!$ orderings are equiprobable). Consider the event "$A$ is the first in the queue". (This event does not mention $B, C$ or other people in the queue: they will appear in the other questions.) What is its probability?

My solution: If $A$*****, then I think there are $5!$ possibilities for order of $5$ people and **Prob=$\frac{5!}{  6!}.$**

But test checker doesn't accept my solution. What is wrong in my solution?

Comment: Have you tried to simplify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. Maybe the checker wants a simplified expression, note that $\frac{5!}{6!} = \frac{1}{6}$. Another way of seeing this is that any of the 6 people has the same odds of being first, hence probability $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try to write 1/6 and it worked. Before this, I wrote numbers like 0.16...

Answer (score 0):

I will use the formula for classical probability. Namely
$$ \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{A})=\dfrac{1\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{6!}=\dfrac{5!}{6!}=\frac{1}{6},         $$
where $\mathcal{A}$ is an event that the people $A$ is first in the queue. So indeed your solution is correct.